# How to get StreamSets Record Fields Type inside Jython Evaluator

Tags: hive, bigdata, jython, kudu, streamsets

I have a StreamSets pipeline, where I read from a remote SQL Server database using JDBC component as an origin and put the data into a Hive and a Kudu Data Lake.

I'm facing some issues with the type Binary Columns, as there is no Binary type support in Impala, which I use to access both Hive and Kudu.

I decided to convert the Binary type columns (Which flows in the pipeline as Byte_Array type) to String and insert it like that.

I tried to use a Field Type Converter element to convert all Byte_Array types to String, but it didn't work. So I used a Jython component to convert all arr.arr types to String. It works fine, until I got a Null value on that field, so the Jython type was None.type and I was unable to detect the Byte_Array type and unable to convert it to String. So I couldn't insert it into Kudu.

Any help how to get StreamSets Record Field Types inside Jython Evaluator? Or any suggested work around for the problem I'm facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `sdcFunctions.getFieldNull()` to test whether the field is `NULL_BYTE_ARRAY`. For example:

```
import array

def convert(item):
  return ':-)'

def is_byte_array(record, k, v):
  # getFieldNull expect a field path, so we need to prepend the '/'
  return (sdcFunctions.getFieldNull(record, '/'+k) == NULL_BYTE_ARRAY 
          or (type(v) == array.array and v.typecode == 'b'))

for record in records:
  try:
    record.value = {k: convert(v) if is_byte_array(record, k, v) else v 
                    for k, v in record.value.items()}
    output.write(record)

  except Exception as e:
    error.write(record, str(e))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this

Answer (score 1):

So here is my final solution:

- You can use the logic below to detect any StreamSets type inside the Jython component by using the NULL_CONSTANTS:

  ```
  NULL_BOOLEAN, NULL_CHAR, NULL_BYTE, NULL_SHORT, NULL_INTEGER, NULL_LONG, 
  NULL_FLOAT, NULL_DOUBLE, NULL_DATE, NULL_DATETIME, NULL_TIME, NULL_DECIMAL, 
  NULL_BYTE_ARRAY, NULL_STRING, NULL_LIST, NULL_MAP
  ```

The idea is to save the value of the field in a temp variable, set the value of the field to be None and use the function **sdcFunctions.getFieldNull** to know the StreamSets type by comparing it to one of the NULL_CONSTANTS.

```
import binascii

def toByteArrayToHexString(value):
  if value is None:
    return NULL_STRING
  value = '0x'+binascii.hexlify(value).upper()
  return value

for record in records:
  try:

    for colName,value in record.value.items():
      temp = record.value[colName]
      record.value[colName] = None
      if sdcFunctions.getFieldNull(record,'/'+colName) is NULL_BYTE_ARRAY:
        temp = toByteArrayToHexString(temp)
      record.value[colName] = temp

    output.write(record)
  except Exception as e
    error.write(record, str(e))
```

**Limitation:**
 The code above converts the Date type to Datetime type only when it has a value (When its not NULL)

Comment: Curious as to why you didn't go with the `(type(v) == array.array and v.typecode == 'b')` test to see if the value is a byte array?

Comment: Because I want to get the exact type used in StreamSets without involving Jython conversions in anyways. I think Jython type is redundant information if you already have the StreamSets type. Also, I'm not sure if the StreamSets to Jython type conversion is a one to one mapping. What do you think about that? Another thing, after this line "record.value[colName] = None" the Jython type will be None.type and I don't want to check for that.